# Distributed OpenGL Rendering

Tags: opengl, cluster-computing, visualization

I'm attempting to find a generic solution to distributing OpenGL rendering across a cluster of machines. I've seen [Chromium](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chromium/), but it appears to be dead and doesn't support GL 3.x (much less than 4.x).

Any other suggestions for a library or GL wrapper than can allow unmodified (or lightly modified) apps to run on a visualization cluster / display wall?

(I'm not asking for a *tool* suggestion, per se, but any libraries or projects that facilitate modern OpenGL apps to distribute the rendering load across multiple machines.)

Comment: Is this intended for a real-time rendering application?  If it's not you might get more success with looking at a ray-tracing engine as they tend to be designed with distributed computing in mind.

Comment: That's a very non-trivial problem to the point that e.g. nVidia sells explicit hardware support for that: [GPUdirect](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect). Thing with distributed rendering is that 2-3 round trip times on an typical ordinary network are approximately a complete frame's worth of time, and you haven't rendered anything yet.